# will a 6GB of RAM will be fine and efficiant to run in 32-bit Ubuntu?

Tags: 32-bit, ram

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 in a Intel Dual Core 3 GHz processor with 2 GB of RAM and I would like to buy a 4 GB of RAM extra and what best I can use it more efficiently and how I am supposed to achieve that ?

My Plan is to run some Database Server.

Comment: Shopping recommendations are not on-topic here ;)

Comment: 32 bit OS will not utilize 6GB RAM

Comment: @RanaMuhammadWaqas see below answers my friend,:0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will a 6GB of RAM will be fine and efficiant to run in 32-bit Ubuntu?

Yes. But 2 will be sufficient to run Ubuntu too. Ubuntu defaults to the PAE kernel for 4Gb+ support on 32 bits so you will be fine. PAE has a maximum of 64Gb.

> My Plan is to run some Database Server.

A database server will benefit from more memory. But it is impossible for us to answer if it runs efficiently since this is very very dependent on the amount of users, bandwidth, and a lot more. Memory is just a small facet in this.

Comment: up to now from my plan , 3 users and that too from local network

Comment: Then 2Gb is more than enough and 6Gb is doing it comfortably :-D We are doing +-250 with 16Gb ;)

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to utilize all 6GB of RAM with the generic Linux kernel, you will have to install a 64-bit edition of Ubuntu. 32-bit systems are only able to exploit 4GB of RAM (at most).

Another option, if you want to keep the 32-bit OS, is to use a PAE (physical address extension) kernel that will allow the OS to "see" more than 4GB of RAM, but in order for this to work, your CPU must also support PAE.

I does not matter what RAM you will buy, as long as frequencies conform to what your processor supports.

Comment: "Physical Address Extension is a technology which allows 32 bit operating systems to use up to 64 Gb of memory (RAM),"  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingPAE

Comment: OK, what is your point?

Comment: Also note that most modern processors support PAE, but in order to make sure it is best to research whether your specific one does.

Comment: I think @Rinzwind talking about you didnt mention that the specifications as 64Gb of RAM with a PAE kernels.

Comment: @errikos that PAE is **default** in Ubuntu so the 1st part of the statement is true for Linux in general but not for Ubuntu ;)